# android when i use moveTaskToBack(true) my app starts again from first activity

Tags: android

my app has two activities .
when user opens the app . 
activity A is opens. 
then user clicks on the button and activity B is opens .
in activity B when user tuch a button

```
moveTaskToBack(true);
```

is run . and activity goes to background .

my problem is After this event When the user clicks on the app icon . activity A is come 
While it should be activity B

Comment: what are you trying to achieve? what are you using moveTaskToBack for? have you finished activity A before start activity B?

Comment: no i dont finished activity A . Because i want Users can go back from B to A .